# What is the proper way to define a list in my model and display item counts for each list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, model, razor-pages

In an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages web application using Entity Framework I wish to have an Index page, that displays news articles' titles in a list, with comment counts under them. On clicking the titles, a details page opens, that show the title, article text and comments underneath. So what I am trying to achieve with Razor Pages right now is a very simple Hacker News-like page. However, I can't figure out the way to assign comments to articles properly and display comment counts on the index page.

I created the model like this:

```
namespace Teszt01.Models
{
    public class Comment
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string CommentText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Teszt01.Models
{
    public class Article
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ArticleText { get; set; }
        public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I decided to use a List<>, however I'm unsure whether it's is OK to use, but after browsing the Microsoft Docs, Stack Overflow and Googling the issue, I couldn't figure out a better way.
Afterwards, I used scaffolding, and tried editing the Index page, to display comment counts, without luck:

```
@page
@model Teszt01.Pages.Articles.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "News feed";
}

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.Article) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a>
                @* trying to display the number of comments: *@
                <p>@item.Comments.Count(modelItem => item.Comments)</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This doesn't work, nothing is shown under the article titles. In a process of trial and error I tried changing the line that is supposed to display the comment count, but that didn't help either and I've ran out of ideas.

I haven't touched the controller (yet), so here's how it looks like:

```
namespace Teszt01.Pages.Articles
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Teszt01.Models.Teszt01Context _context;

        public IndexModel(Teszt01.Models.Teszt01Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Article> Article { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Article = await _context.Article.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder whether the model I'm using is correct and if so, how to show comment counts on the index page, and properly implement adding new comments to articles on the details page.

Comment: Where is `Model` defined on your Razor page?

Comment: Did u try  > @item.Comments.Count() if it didn't work, please show controller & Model

Comment: @RonaldHaan I updated the post with the definition.

Comment: @AssafOur I tried your solution, but I get ArgumentNullException while the page is being loaded. I'll update the original port with my controller, however I haven't touched it yet, it's the basic one that is autogenerated by Visual Studio scaffolding.

Comment: I think the line `@model Teszt01.Pages.Articles.IndexModel` should be `@model Teszt01.Models.Article`. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

you need to have FK in your class 
something ~ this

```
 public class Article
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ArticleText { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }

}

//Controller 
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var ArticalsWithComents = await _context.Article.Include(a => a.Comment);
         return View(ArticalsWithComents.ToListAsync());
}
```